# Cannot instantiate the type ResteasyClientBuilder

Tags: java, resteasy, rest-client

I am trying to build a simple Resteasy client, using proxy framework. I am getting a error, "Cannot instantiate the type ResteasyClientBuilder".
This is the Client class.

```
package com.RestClient.Clients;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyWebTarget;

import com.RestClient.Models.Student;

public class ClientClass {
    ResteasyClient client;
    ResteasyWebTarget base_target,student_target;
    ClientInterface proxy;
    public ClientClass() {
        client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();<---------error
        base_target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8080/demorest/webresources/"));
        student_target = base_target.path("students");
    }
    public int registerStudent(Student s) {
        Response res = proxy.createStudent(s);
        return res.getStatus();
        
    }
}
```

I was following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/resteasy-client-tutorial) tutorial.

Answer (score 10):

Version 4.0.0 of RestEasy Client converted ResteasyClientBuilder to an abstract class and provided `ResteasyClientBuilderImpl` as the actual implementation that you're looking for.

But you should be using the new `builder` when generating a client.

```
client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
base_target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/demorest/webresources/");
```

Comment: The `ResteasyClientBuilderImpl` is internal implementation detail. Use `ClientBuilder.newBuilder()` instead (see https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/5.0.1.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html).